# SPF records, combining suggested records

Tags: email, mx-record, spf, amazon-ses

I have a domain that sends automated email using Amazon SES, regular email using Google Apps and a monthly newsletter using MailChimp. I want to combine the three suggested SPF records into one, but I am not sure of the correct syntax.

MailChimp suggests:

```
v=spf1 mx ptr include:servers.mcsv.net ~all
```

Amazon SES suggests:

```
 v=spf1 include:amazonses.com -all
```

Google Apps suggests:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

So I think the correct spf record should be:

```
v=spf1 mx ptr include:servers.mcsv.net include:amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Is this correct?

I am not sure I need or want the mx and ptr, but that is what MailChimp suggested. Does the MX mean I need to add an additional MX record? Also can anyone explain the purpose of PTR, does it mean I also need to add a CNAME record?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to need an SPF record for Amazon SES as mentioned in their documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is ok.

> Does the MX mean I need to add an additional MX record? Also can
>   anyone explain the purpose of PTR, does it mean I also need to add a
>   CNAME record?

No. It means that all `A` records for all `MX` records of your domain is tested in order of `MX priority`. If client IP matchs one of them, then your SPF pass.

It's is the same wit `ptr`. The hostname or hostnames for the client IP are looked up using `PTR` queries. The hostnames are then validated: at least one of the **A** records for a `PTR` hostname must match the original client IP. You don't need to add a `CNAME`.